# Is there a way to suppress errors in the *Messages* buffer?

Tags: font-lock, message

I have a persistent problem with some jit-lock-function somewhere whenever I compile. I'm actually invoking the visual studio compiler, and I assume some of the output is somehow abhorrent to emacs. I updated to a newer version of emacs today because I found that there was an error in cc-fonts.el that would cause trouble, but even with that fix I still see this:

```el
Error during redisplay: (jit-lock-function 80427) signaled (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)
```

It doesn't seem to be causing any trouble, and it's not worth any more of my time to fix it. Can I get the messages buffer to stop showing it to me?

Edit: It's worth noting that it's many variations on this message that are being displayed, so the function number (80427 in my example) changes on almost every line. That means I end up with hundreds of these messages filling up my messages buffer, pushing out any meaningful information.

Comment: My advice is to just ignore it. It's good, not bad, to have error msgs in `*Messages*`. (Just one opinion.)

Comment: Normally I would agree, but the problem is that my messages buffer is absolutely filled with these messages, and it's hard to see anything that's ACTUALLY worth paying attention to. A single short compile can generate 50 of these, so the buffer quickly becomes filled with nothing else.

Comment: The reason this "*doesn't seem to be causing any trouble*" is because an error occurring during redisplay is ignored. Try to find out what is calling `jit-lock-function` and passing it a number instead of a string. Check your font-lock code. Check other things that can call functions during redisplay, such as mode-line constructs. Recursively bisect your init file (commenting-out 1/2, then 3/4,...) until you locate the offending code. You can use command `comment-region` to comment (or with `C-u` uncomment) the region. It's very quick. (Keep other error msgs coming to `*Messages*` - useful.)